# Is it possible to use an arbitrary address as an AWS VPC route table target?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

When I try to add a route in the AWS Console's VPC's route table page, it only shows internet gateways and nat gateways. Is there a way I can use an arbitrary IP address (in the vpc) as a target instead? This seems necessary to allow openvpn tunneling between things in the VPC and my on-prem network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only one of the following as the target in the route table ([document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-route.html)):

> Internet gateway or virtual private gateway, NAT instance, NAT
>   gateway, VPC peering connection, network interface, or egress-only
>   Internet gateway.

For VPN between the VPC and on-premises network, you should have a virtual private gateway in the VPC which should be the [target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/SetUpVPNConnections.html#vpn-configure-routing) in the route table.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm trying to find a free solution if possible, since for example a VPN connection from AWS costs ~$36 per month.

Comment: VPN is quite different from a route table. Suggest you accept this answer, then ask the question you really need answered - the higher level "how do I achieve xyz" question.

Comment: A "NAT Instance" as used here in the docs is an oversimplification.  What it *really* means is "an EC2 instance with source/dest address check disabled" -- which is how you do what you are trying to do.  You can use the instance-id as the target in the route table, after disabling the source/dest check on the instance running OpenVPN.

Comment: Note also that the IP addresses on the far-side of OpenVPN must be addresses that are *not* from the VPC CIDR block.

Comment: @Tim good idea, done.